# Datapower service migration to different region/environment

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am new to Datapower and have developed/configured a service which is working fine at the moment, I want to take this to production and for that need to create artefacts. Could you help me telling the standard practice and how /what all files I should include ? I heard about manifest file to include but not sure where should I find them.

Also heard about the mkick but not even know what does it do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the IBM docs/infocenter, look for e.g. "deployment policy", identify the places in your service that would have to be different between your stages....

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan suggests Deployment policies will likely be of interest for changing settings between your Development and Production environments.

You will want to take a configuration export of your service and use the options to include referenced objects.

Also keep in mind certificates and keys are not included in the export, so if you have any referenced for the configuration, you will need to update those settings on your prod environment before this service can be active.

Comment: Just o answer my question - we have used b64 encoding with Cygwin once manifiest file is prepared. Manifest file is the list of important datapower objects we want to include into b64 encoding so that it could be successfully deployed in other environements.

Comment: Let me know if anyone needs specific steps to follow. I am happy to provide.

Answer (score 1):

As answered earlier by Jimb. We can export the service from the DEV, STG environments and import them to Production Environments.

You can use deployment policies, Be sure you first import deployment policy and then the service(Because you have to select the deployment policy when importing the service).

Also You have to export the Keys, Certs and necessary artifacts from the previous environment.

Hope this helps.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Deployment is an integral part of any development architecture. Code deployment is a process of moving the code from your development environment to QA (Quality Assessment) env’t or from conveying env’t to pre-production env’t etc.
In DP the code deployment mean bundling all your code and dependent resources into one env’t and to the target env’t. However, to move from one env’t to the other env’t in practical you may have to face key challenges:

For instance in the process of moving code from dev to QA, both the structure remains the same. But, the detail is different why? Because IP and port no which is available in dev env’t it may not be working if we move along with QA env’t. Therefore, you should change that. The second thing also the backend server details of the dev env’t is also different from the QA env’t. That also needs to change. However, in order to address these challenges, the DP has a set of tools. That tool is the so-called Deployment policy.

Generally, whenever to make deployment and migration we need to keep in mind is :
Identify from and to which application domain is taken place, usually this migration process is taken place from high-level appliance DP to the lower one the process definitely failed. 
If the process is taken place the same level appliance say from XI50 to XI52 we need to take care of the code from the lower level firmware to the new one may not be working because the new one may have advanced features.
Migration is working with env’t variables and we need to check that env’t variable. How? Use the deployment policy. However, deployment policy has one weakness is cannot look inside your SSL file and cannot make a change over there. You have to do a deployment policy by yourself.